Need help understanding the switching of integral limits with Fubini's theorem: $\int_0^cm(\{x:|f(x)|>t\})dt=\int_{\{x:c\geq |f(x)|\geq 0\}}|f(x)|dx$
Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}, m)$ with $m$ being the Lebesgue measure and $c > 0$. I have to admit that I am quite bad with using Fubini's theorem outside of calculus type problems of abstract proofs. In particular, I'm not really comfortable using the said theorem with distribution functions $\lambda_f(t) = m(\{x: |f(x)| > t\})$. In particular, I can't quite convince myself why we integrate over the set $\{x:c\geq |f(x)|\geq 0\}$ when turning
$$\int_0^cm(\{x:|f(x)|>t\})dt$$
into
$$\int_{\{x:c\geq |f(x)|\geq 0\}}|f(x)|dx$$
with the intermediary step
$$\int_0^cm(\{x:|f(x)|>t\})dt = \int_{\{x:c\geq |f(x)|\geq 0\}}\int_0^{|f(x)|} 1dtdx$$
Let us write
$$ I = \int_0^cm(\{x:|f(x)|>t\})dt$$
and
$$J = \int_{\{x:c\geq |f(x)|\geq 0\}}\int_0^{|f(x)|} 1dtdx$$
My verbal "line of reasoning" on performing the switch of the order of integrals for  is as follows:
Since the condition of the integrand in $I$ is that $|f(x)| > t$, it is clear that in the new double integral $J$, the innermost integral is the integral of any function of $t$, in this case the constant function $1$, up to $|f(x)|$. The lower bound will be given by the original lower bound of $t$ in $I$, i.e. zero. Let us then figure out the domain of integration for the outermost integral in $J$. When $x$ is such that $|f(x)|$ satisfies some inequality, I will say (imprecisely) that $x$ satisfies the inequality. Since $|f|\geq 0$ there is no stringent lower bound condition that any $x$ would have to satisfy: If the function |f| in question were to be some other $g$ with the possibility of $g(x) < 0$, then the lower bound that any $x$ would have to satisfy would be given by $\inf_x g(x)$. As for the upper bound since $t$ can be at most $c$ in $I$, we have to set the upper bound to be $c$ in $J$ as well.
This last condition seems to be what bugs me the most, and which I can't really convince myself about. As far as I recall, in basic calculus when you determine the new integration bounds, you'd have to figure out what is the largest value that, in our case, $|f(x)|$ can get. Well technically, $|f(x)|$ could get values up to and including $+\infty$, just not in any set with positive measure. And therefore my verbal line of reasoning is quite blunt, and possibly inconsistent, with this rule of thumb from calculus. So, what would be a correct verbal reasoning for the new domain of integration?

I am missing something. Shouldn't it be $\int_{{x:|f(x)|\leq c}}|f(x)|dx=\int_0^cm({x:t<|f(x)|\leq c})dt$ ?

@Snoop Maybe? My question is a derivative from another question I had. My original question was reasonably satisfied under the assumption that $\int_0^cm({x:|f(x)| > t})dt = \int_{{x:c\geq |f(x)|}}|f(x)|dx$, so I figured that it had to be so. It could be that I am wrong.
The original equality which gave me trouble is $\int_c^\infty m({x:|f(x)| > t})dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\max{|f(x)| - c, 0}dx$, which is reasonably solved by $\pm$ the integral from zero to $c$, and by using the aforementioned equality as well as known equality $|f|_p^p=\int_0^\infty py^{p-1}\lambda_f(x)dx$.

Let $g=\mathbf{1}_{{|f|\leq c}}|f|$. Then $\int gdx=\int_0^\infty m({g>t})dt=\int_0^c m({g>t})dt=\int_0^c m({t<|f|\leq c})dt$. Would you agree?

The identity you write is incorrect: notice that if $t\in[0,c]$ then $f^{-1}((t,\infty)) = f^{-1}((c,\infty))\cup f^{-1}((t,c])$ hence $m(f(x)>t) = m(f(x)>c)+m(t<f(x)\leq c)$. It follows that
$$
\int_{t \in [0,c]} m(|f(x)|>t)dt = c.m(|f(x)|>c) + \int_{t\in [0,c]} m(t<|f(x)|\leq c)dt
$$
and Fubini's theorem shows that $\int_{0\leq t \leq c} m(t<f(t)\leq c)dt = \int_{0\leq |f(x)|\leq c} |f(x)|dx$.
To see this last equality in detail, recall that Fubini's theorem states that for $f$ integrable, if we write $\mathrm{d}\nu_d$ for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$ (where $d \in \{1,2\}$), $E_x = \left\{t\in \mathbb R: (x,t) \in E\right\}$, and $f_x\colon E_x \to \mathbb R$ by $f_x(t) = f(x,t)$, then $f_x$ is integrable for almost almost all $x$ and the function
$$
F_t(x)= \int_{t\in E_x} f(x,t)d\nu_1
$$
is integrable with $\int_{E} f(x,t)d\nu_2 = \int_{x: E_x \neq \emptyset} \int F_t(x)d\nu_1$, that is
$$
\int_E f(x,t)\mathrm{d}\nu_2 =\int_{x:E_x \neq \emptyset} \left(\int_{t \in E_x}(f_x(t) d\nu_1\right)d\nu_1 =\int_{x:E_x \neq \emptyset} \left(\int_{t \in E_x} f(x,t) d\nu_1\right)d\nu_1
$$
and similarly $\int_E 1 d\nu_2 = \int_{t: E_t \neq \emptyset} F_x(t) d\nu_1$, where $F_x$ and $E_t$ are defined by swapping the roles of $x$ and $t$.
Now if $E=\left\{(x,t)\in \mathbb R^2:t\in [0,c], c\geq |f(x)|>t\right\}$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
E_t &= \left\{x  \in \mathbb R: (x,t)\in E\right\} = \left\{x \in \mathbb R: t\in [0,c], |f(x)|>t\right\}\\
&= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \left\{x \in \mathbb R: c\geq |f(x)|>t\right\}, & \text{ if } t \in [0,c] \\ \emptyset & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.
\end{split}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{split}
E_x &= \left\{ t \in \mathbb R: (x,t)\in E\right\} = \left\{t \in \mathbb R: 0 \leq t \leq c, t<|f(x)|\leq c\right\}\\ &= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}  [0,|f(x)|), & \text{if } |f(x)|\leq c, \\ \emptyset & \text{if } |f(x)|>c \end{array} \right.
\end{split}
$$
Thus
$$
F_x(t) = \int_{x \in E_t} 1.d\nu_1 = m(E_t) = \mathbb 1_{[0,c]}(t). m(\left\{ x: |f(x)|>t\right\})
$$
and
$$
F_t(x) = \int_{t \in E_x} 1 .d\nu_1 = m(E_x) = \mathbb 1_{|f(x)|\leq c}.|f(x)|
$$
so that Fubini's theorem ensures that
$$
\int_{t\in [0,c]} m(\left\{x : c\geq |f(x)|>t\right\})d\nu_1 = \int_{E} 1d\nu_2 = \int_{\left\{x:0\leq |f(x)|\leq c \right\}} |f(x)|d\nu_1
$$

You are allowed to switch the order of integration when the integrand is
nonnegative and both spaces you integrate over are fixed (Tonelli's theorem).
To get the integral in that form, use the common trick of indicator functions:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_0^c m (x : | f (x) | > t) dt & = & \int_0^c \int_{\mathbb{R}} I (| f
  (x) | > t) m (dx) dt\\
  & = & \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_0^c I (| f (x) | > t) dtm (dx)\\
  & = & \int_{\mathbb{R}} \min (c, | f (x) |) m (dx).
\end{eqnarray*}
In particular, your title is wrong.
